# Is there a web interface within paypal to create billing plans

Tags: paypal

So Im reading through the documentation on 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/
If I understand correctly we create one plan and then the agreement per user. Meaning the plan is not a per user kind of thing.

If the plan is not a per user kind of thing, Is there a paypal page from within paypal where I can actually create the plan? Seems strange that I can only create plans programmatically, unless of course plans are directly associated to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no web inteface within PayPal to create a plan.
You can do this only by REST API inteface.

The recurring payment should be created following below steps.
Step 1: Create a plan from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-plan)

Step 2: Update a plan(Active a Plan) from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#update-a-plan)

Step 3: Create an agreement under a plan from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-an-agreement)

Step 4: Get the response of Step3, get the "links" property, redirect the buyer to the "href" of "links"

Step 5: After buy agree the payment on Step4, excute the agreement from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-agreement)

Please also refer to the links below regarding billing plan and billing agreement.

1. [Billing Plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/)
2. [Billing Agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/)

Comment: I've been trying to use that API endpoint but I'm getting "RESOURCE NOT FOUND" "Invalid product id". How could I have a valid product id if the plan hasn't been created yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Try visiting https://sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans if you are testing and using the GUI you can create both products and plans.